# Open url in new tab and paste the copied text

Tags: applescript, safari

I'm new to AppleScript. I want to use AppleScript with Sci-hub page. **In my scenario, I highlight DOI address -> AppleScript will open "Sci-hub.tw" page in new tab on Safari -> paste DOI address to text box -> press Enter / Return.**
I found in many sites and tried to code. It here but my code just open url in new tab, not paste the highligh address.

Please, help me!

Thanks and best regards!

```
on run {input, parameter}
   tell application "Safari"
        activate
        try
        tell window 1 to set current tab to make new tab with properties {URL:"http://www.sci-hub.tw"}
             on error
                open location theURL
        end try
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Safari"
                 activate
                 keystroke "v" using command down
                 delay 0.3
                 key code 36 #return
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: This is pure AppleScript. Are you using this within an Automator workflow or did you just mix up the two terms?

Comment: I mixed two codes from others website.
I don't know about Apple Script so i search in the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, may be helpful to you.

As coded, it does work from **Script Editor** in **macOS High Sierra**; however, for **macOS Mojave**, one minor edit it required to the `tell application "System Events"` *command* in the `on waitForPageToFinishLoadingInSafari()` *handler*, and it is shown in the *comment* `--  # NOTE:` within the *code* below.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set theURL to "http://www.sci-hub.tw"

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    try
        tell window 1 to set current tab to make new tab with properties {URL:theURL}
    on error
        open location theURL
    end try
end tell

my waitForPageToFinishLoadingInSafari()

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "v" using command down
    delay 0.3
    key code 36 #return     
end tell

--  # Handlers:

on waitForPageToFinishLoadingInSafari()
    
    --  # NOTE: For macOS Mojave, change 'UI element 1' to 'UI element 2` in the code below.
    
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat until (accessibility description of ¬
            button 1 of UI element 1 of every group of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
            process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page") contains "Reload this page"
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
    end tell
    
end waitForPageToFinishLoadingInSafari
```

- Note: As coded, it assumes you have the desired search string already on the Clipboard so when System Events does **⌘V**, it is pasted into the text box on the page.

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans *error handling* from your original code it does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

---

## **Update:**

This update is to address explicitly how the OP is using his **Quick Action** *service* in **Automator** as per his comment to this answer.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, has been tested in **macOS Mojave** and works on my system as is.

Replace the *default code* of the **Run AppleScript** *action* with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set theURL to "http://www.sci-hub.tw"
    set theSearchString to (item 1 of input as text)
    
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        try
            tell window 1 to set current tab to make new tab with properties {URL:theURL}
        on error
            open location theURL
        end try
    end tell
    
    my waitForPageToFinishLoadingInSafari()
    
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke theSearchString
        delay 0.2
        key code 36 -- # Enter Key     
    end tell
    
end run


--  # Other Handlers:

on waitForPageToFinishLoadingInSafari()
    
    -- # NOTE: For macOS High Sierra and earlier , change 'UI element 2' to 'UI element 1' in the code below.
    
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat until (accessibility description of ¬
            button 1 of UI element 2 of every group of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
            process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page") contains "Reload this page"
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
    end tell
    
end waitForPageToFinishLoadingInSafari
```

**Note:** In order to use the **Quick Action** *service*, each *application* you trigger it from will need to be added to two locations in:

- **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**

  - **Accessibility**
  - **Automation**

You should be prompted as necessary and you'll need to unlock the **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** *tab* as necessary and check the *application* as necessary. See the images below.

---

[image: Automator Quick Action]

In the following two images, you'll see that **Safari** and **TextEdit** have been added and this is a direct result of using the **Quick Action** *service* from both of these applications. If I were to select something to be searched with **Search With SCI-HUB** from the **Services** menu in, e.g., **Mail**, then it too will need to be added, and again you should be prompted.

[image: Security & Privacy - Accessibility]
[image: Security & Privacy - Automation]

Comment: I'm just curious why you would not use something like `tell application "Safari" to (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1) is "complete"` or `tell application "Safari" to (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in tabs of window 1) contains "loading"` to wait until page has finished loading in Safari

Comment: @wch1zpink, Because they do not work consistently. They also require **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** to be checked on the hidden by default **Develop** menu and in some version of OS X/macOS it has been difficult to get it checked. I had been use the method mentioned by CJK for some time and without issue before he posted it but I like his code better than mine.

Comment: Thank you user3439894. I will try it and tell you the result.

Comment: I'm using MacOS Mojave và Automator.
I tried your code, but it didn't work. The code can open Sci-hub page in new tab, but it cannot paste the copied text on clipboard.
Here, this is the screenshot of automator setting of my workflow.
I'm looking forward to your feedback soon.
Thank you!

Comment: @Bò Bía, I've rewritten my answer with a different _code_ layout, please use it instead of the original _code_. I have added a _comment_ `-- # NOTE:` within the _code_. For macOS Mojave, you'll need to change `UI element 1` **to** `UI element 2`in the `tell application "System Events"` _command_ in the `on waitForPageToFinishLoadingInSafari()` _handler_, which is the _code_ that waits for the page to finish loading in Safari. I reworked the original _code_ so, IMO, it flows better, is easier to read and understand.

Comment: @user3439894 I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much. But your code didn't work. I changed UI element 1 -> UI element 2, however, the Automator performance didn't like my imagine, just opened Sci-hub page in the new tab.
I can't upload my screenshot, so you're hardly to imagine. Sorry!
Did you try the code before answered?

Comment: @Bò Bía, The _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ in my answer works for me in both **macOS High Sierra** and when setting `UI element 2` in **macOS Mojave**. I tested it in both versions of the **OS** in **Script Editor** and **Automator** and it worked without issues. I have no idea what you mean by "_however, the Automator performance didn't like my imagine_" and without seeing a screenshot of your **Automator** _workflow_, sorry I can't help further without it.

Comment: @user3439894 I will describe how i create workflow in Automator on MacOS Mojave because i cannot post my screenshot.
Firstly, i chose Quick Action for document type. Then, i chose "text" in "Workflow receives current" and in "any application". Next, i added "Run AppleScript" to workflow and pasted your code to it. Finally, i saved my workflow.
When i ran the workflow, i highlighted the text and right clicked. In Service menu, i chose the workflow. The Safari opened Sci-hub page in new tab without pasted the copied text.
i know i'm annoying you but i need your help. Please!

Comment: @Bò Bía, See the **Update:** section of my answer, which address explicitly how you are using the Quick Action service in Automator as per your comment to this answer.

Comment: @user3439894 The updated code couldn't work. I thought it happened because of the "repeat" command. So, i deleted it.
Here, it is my modified code.


on run {input, parameters}
 set theURL to "http://www.sci-hub.tw"
 set theSearchString to (item 1 of input as text)
 tell application "Safari"
  activate
  try
   tell window 1 to set current tab to make new tab with properties {URL:theURL}
  on error
   open location theURL
  end try
 end tell
 tell application "System Events"
  keystroke theSearchString
  delay 0.2
  key code 36 -- # Enter Key     
 end tell
end run

Comment: @user3439894 I really appriciated your support and kindness. Thank you!

Comment: @Bò Bía, As I have stated more than once... The _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ in my answer works for me in both **macOS High Sierra** and when setting `UI element 2` in **macOS Mojave**. I tested it in both versions of the **OS** in **Script Editor** and **Automator** and it worked without issues! Sorry, but I do not see what else I can do for you.

Comment: @user3439894 i have read your comment very carefully and i known your code worked on your device but in my device was not. However, i maked it working now with some modify above. My English is not good so it hard to express my opinion. Forgive me. Thank you again.

Comment: so happy I found this information, thank you!
but please could you help me with an update for monterey? Cause it opens the sci-hub page (I've updated it to the correct url) but doesnt put the highlighted text in the search field on sci-hub.
Sorry if I mixed up something, and thank you again for your help!