# How to open a fixed URL + what's in the clipboard via a script & bind it to a shortcut?

Tags: macos, applescript, safari, automation, copy-paste

Will this applescript work?

```
Tell Application "Safari" to open location
"http://www.site.com/"
end tell

Tell Process "Safari"
   Keystroke "l" using command down

Tell application "System Events" to key code
124 using command down

Tell Process "Safari"
   Keystroke "v" using command down
   Keystroke return
end tell
```

Comment: Have you run it? Did you get an error? Did it do anything?

Comment: I don't have a mac actually.  Ive wrote many powershell scripts and was just trying to help a friend out by writing a applescript.  It looks good, but was looking for validation from someone else that it should work as intended.

Comment: @Ryan there are some syntax errors. Please see other threads to see how to fix it. Then ping me, I can test it. This is useful for me too.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applescript https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363521/open-url-in-new-tab-and-paste-the-copied-text

Comment: @Ryan this works for the most part: https://pastebin.com/nmKd8pBm

Comment: That looks good.  What do you mean for the most part?  Are there any errors or does it work hit or miss?

Comment: @ankii What would it be like to shorten it up and add the clipboard right to the url with an & operator.?

Tell Application "Safari" to open location
"http://www.site.com/&(the clipboard as text)"
end tell

Comment: @ankii, care to test something else out for me?  My friend wants to automate it with a hotkey.  Using what provided in the pastebin.  Do you think this would work for that applescript?

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote

Comment: @ankii - I know you said this could be beneficial to you as well.  Check this one out.--> https://pastebin.com/3G9TENZx

Comment: @Ryan we're in different timelines. :) Also, when I said "most part", I meant that "enter" & "right" key press were not written. Now it works: https://pastebin.com/Jz85eAPz and yes, any AppleScript can be bound to a shortcut using automator's service feature. you found the correct question for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up going with this.

```
set this_text to the clipboard   
set theURL to "[url]http://www.site.com/[/url]" & this_text

tell application "Safari"    
   activate    
   if (count documents) is 0 then make new document    
   tell window 1
       set tabTest to URL of tab 1    
       try
           tabTest -- throws an error if the window has no tabs   
           set current tab to (make new tab with properties{URL:theURL})    
       on error    
           set URL of tab 1 to theURL    
       end try    
   end tell
```

end tell

Comment: Can you explain in more details what the code does?

Comment: I have to agree with nohillside, because I fail to see the _logic_ in your _code_, in particular why the `set tabTest to URL of tab 1` and the `try` _statement_ that follows. If **Safari** has any _browser windows_ open then there is always a `tab 1` and the `on error` will never trigger. Additionally `"[url]http://www.site.com/[/url]"` is malformed and will never open because of `[url]` and `[/url]`. Please see my updated answer that handles the typical different scenarios of the state of **Safari**.

Answer (score 2):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will do as you asked:

```applescript
set the clipboard to "questions/392514/i-want-to-write-a-script-to-open-a-fixed-url-whats-in-the-clipboard-ex-open"

set myURL to "https://apple.stackexchange.com/" & (the clipboard)

tell application "Safari" to ¬
    tell its first window to ¬
        set its current tab to ¬
            (make new tab with properties {URL:myURL})
```

If you run the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, as is, it will open to your question.

The first line of *code* is just there for testing purposes as well as the `"https://apple.stackexchange.com/"` part of `myURL`. Change it to what you want and comment out or delete the first line to use it normally.

To incorporate that into something more robust to account for the current state of **Safari**, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* handles the typical different scenarios:

```applescript
set the clipboard to "questions/392514/i-want-to-write-a-script-to-open-a-fixed-url-whats-in-the-clipboard-ex-open"

set myURL to "https://apple.stackexchange.com/" & (the clipboard)

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    if (count documents) is equal to 0 then
        make new document
        repeat until exists its first window
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
        set URL of its current tab of its first window to myURL
    else
        set firstTabURL to URL of its first tab of its first window
        if {"favorites://", "topsites://", missing value} contains firstTabURL then
            set URL of its current tab of its first window to myURL
        else
            tell its first window to ¬
                set its current tab to ¬
                    (make new tab with properties {URL:myURL})
        end if
    end if
end tell
```

Again, the first line of *code* is just there for testing purposes as well as the `"https://apple.stackexchange.com/"` part of `myURL`. Change it to what you want and comment out or delete the first line to use it normally.

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code*  was tested on **macOS High Sierra**.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This hack also works.

Bind this to a keyboard shortcut using one of these answers:

- [How do I assign a keyboard shortcut to an AppleScript I wrote?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote)

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1 to make new tab
    open location "site.com"
end tell

delay 0.5

tell application "System Events"
    delay 0.5
    keystroke "l" using command down
    key code 124 -- right key, since URL is selected already
    keystroke "v" using command down
    delay 1
    key code 36 -- enter. But beware, it can "enter" any popup that appears too.
end tell
```

Comment: RE: "This hack also works." -- You are right, it's a **hack**! 1. **Safari** does not understand the `open location` _command_ because it is not a part of its **AppleScript** _dictionary_, it's a part of **Standard Additions** and doesn't belong in a `tell application "Safari"` _block_. If another browser was the default it would open in the other browser, not **Safari**. 2. This construct `keystroke (key code 124)` is not at all necessary, simply `key code 124` is all that's necessary, and the same goes for the other `key code` _command_ in your _code_. Continued in next comment...

Comment: **3**. There is absolutely no reason to be using **UI Scripting** in this _use case_ because **Safari** has the _vocabulary_ along with `the clipboard` _command_ from **Standard Additions** to accomplish this simply in a very clean manner as shown in my answer. There is no need to resort to using **UI Scripting**, and its should only be used when there is no other, or more proper, way to accomplish the task!

Comment: I only modified what I got in the question. // thanks for not downvoting it (:

Comment: Re **1** , for some reason, focus was shifting back to original when using `tell its first window to 
        set its current tab to 
            (make new tab with properties {URL:myURL})` when I tried it yesterday. So I broke it into two parts.